# Proving the Sum of an Arithmetic Series Using Mathematical Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

How do I prove by mathematical induction that for any natural number $n$, $n \geq 1$, we have $1 + 6 + 11 + \dots + (5n-4) = \frac{n(5n-3)}{2}$?

I know that we have a base case, $n = 1$. I also know that a proof by induction proceeds in two parts.

The first part is the base case, in which you prove the statement for a "starting" value of $n$. Usually it is $1$ or $0$, but sometimes it may be necessary to start with a higher (or even lower) value if the problem calls for it.

This problem says we want to prove something for $n \geq 1$, so our base case will be $n=1$.

So in our case, the problem becomes:

Prove that IF $1 + 6 + 11 + \dots + (5p-4) = \frac{p(5p-3)}{2}$, THEN $1 + 6 + 11 + \dots + (5p-4) + (5(p+1)-4) = \frac{(p+1)(5(p+1)-3)}{2}$.

But I’m stuck on how to go from here.

Comment: Substitute the result of the IF part in the LHS of the final equation: $\dfrac {p(5p−3)}{2}+5p+1= \ldots $. Now compute it.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it

Comment: \begin{align*}
&\frac{p(5p-3)}{2} + (5p+5-4) = \frac{(p+1)(5(p+1)-3)}{2} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\frac{5p^2 - 3p + 10p + 2}{2} = \frac{(5p^2 + 2p + 5p + 5 - 3)}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\underbrace{1 + 6 + 11 + \dots + (5p-4)}_{\text{assumption}} + (5(p+1)-4)
&=
\underbrace{\frac{p(5p-3)}{2}}_{\text{assumption}}+(5(p+1)-4)\\
&=
\frac{p(5p-3)+2(5(p+1)-4)}{2}
\end{align}
$$
so we need to verify that:
$$
\begin{align}
p(5p-3)+2(5(p+1)-4)
&=
5p^2-3p+10p+10-8\\
&=
5p^2+7p+2
\end{align}
$$
equals:
$$
\begin{align}
(p+1)(5(p+1)-3)
&=
(p+1)(5p+2)\\
&=
5p^2+7p+2
\end{align}
$$